# Custom datatype (MPI_Datatype datatype)?

Tags: openmpi

Is there such a thing as a custom datatype in MPI, or do you have to flatten everything into a text string and pass as MPI_CHAR? If you are required to flatten everything, is there a built-in function I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better answer is [MPI_Type_create_struct](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Type_create_struct.3.php). It allows you to replicate your struct datatype and pass it around, there is a great example of it's use at [DeinoMPI](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Type_create_struct.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [MPI_Type_contiguous](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Type_contiguous.3.php) (the link is to the documentation). It allows you to block out a specific amount of space based on basic data types, and their respective offsets.